# Duplicate on MYSQL results when using inner join

Tags: mysql, duplicates, inner-join

I am trying to list two attributes(booking.roomno and room.price) with the condition that "booking.DATETO is not null" from two different tables.

Table: Booking[image: Booking Table]! Table:Room! [image]

I have tried using this command

```
 select booking.roomno,room.price 
 from booking 
 inner join room on booking.ROOMNO=room.roomno 
 where booking.dateto is not null
```

although the return results came in with duplicated roomno and price like shown below
[image]

Comment: Use `distinct` in your select

Comment: You're not specifying the `type` in your query, so it's joining with all the types. I don't know why it's giving the same price for all of them, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`room.roomno` is not unique. It is only unique within a given hotel and your room table contains multiple hotels. You are going to have to specify hotelno in your join condition as well. Also since you might have multiple bookings for the same room (i.e., duplicates in booking table) you will need to do a DISTINCT to prevent that (but then you have to include the hotelno column in your field list):

```
select DISTINCT booking.roomno,room.price, room.hotelno
from booking 
inner join room on booking.ROOMNO=room.roomno 
   AND booking.hotelno=room.hotelno
where booking.dateto is not null
```

Comment: Also the room type: `single`, `double`, etc.

Comment: I think if you look closely at the room table you'll see that the hotelno is the key we're interested in, and not the type...

Comment: Yeah, didn't notice that the type is different depending on the hotel.

Answer (score 1):

You have two bookings for the same room so the returned rows match your inner join. You seem to be trying to fetch all the rooms that have bookings. You would achieve that by adding DISTINCTROW before the selected fields.

```
select DISTINCTROW booking.hotelno, booking.roomno,room.price 
from booking 
inner join room on booking.ROOMNO=room.roomno AND
    booking.HOTELNO=room.HOTELNO
where booking.dateto is not null
```

Comment: This will still give duplicate `roomno` when the `price` is different.

Comment: Agreed. Take a look at Peter Bowers' reply as well. He noted that there may be the same room number in multiple hotels. Edited my answer to correspond to that.